# How does one set the tabIndex attribute on a draft-js instance?

Tags: reactjs, tabindex, draftjs

How does one pass a tabIndex value to the draft-js editor so it can participate in the "tab-between-components" cycle?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings.html#content

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like you would any other React component:

```
<Draft tabIndex='1' .../>
```

This isn't documented anywhere on the Draft side that I can find, but here's the React side of the story: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html.

Comment: That actually doesn't work for me. I can't get the Editor input into the tab order (tabIndex = 0).